# Get type from property with Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

Using Roslyn I'm trying to interpret some code that looks something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public override Type BarType
    {
        get { return typeof(MyBar); }
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is get `MyBar` and then get that type as a symbol, but I'm not sure if this is even something that is possible or practical to do. I'm going to have several classes that look like this and all derive from a base class.

Given the `ClassDeclarationSyntax` for `Foo`, I can do this:

```
var prop = syntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>()
              .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Identifier.ToString() == "BarType");
```

Or given the `INamedTypeSymbol` for `Foo`, I can do this:

```
var member = symbol.GetMembers("BarType").FirstOrDefault();
```

But I don't know where to go from there.

Ultimately I want to be able to get the symbol for `MyBar` for further analysis, so maybe even getting the string `"MyBar"` isn't going to help because it's not fully qualified.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:

I'm getting a project and a compilation like this:

```
var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
var project = workspace.OpenProjectAsync(projectPath).Result;
var compilation = project.GetCompilationAsync().Result;
```

`compilation` is a `CSharpCompilation` here. From there I do something like this:

```
foreach (var doc in project.Documents)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Analyzing {doc.Name}");

    //var model = doc.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
    var tree = doc.GetSyntaxTreeAsync().Result;
    var root = tree.GetRoot();
    var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
    var classes = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();

    foreach (var syntax in classes)
    {
        var symbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(syntax);
        //... need to analyze properties in the class here...
    }
}
```

Either way I get `model` I end up with a `SyntaxTreeSemanticModel` which doesn't seem to have a `GetTypeSymbol` method.

Answer (score 8):

You should look for the `ReturnStatementSyntax` and `TypeOfExpressionSyntax`. This contains the type `MyBar`. With the `SemanticModel` you can get the `SymbolInfo` like this:

```
var classDeclarationSyntaxs = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
foreach ( var classDeclarationSyntax in classDeclarationSyntaxs )
{
    var propertyDeclarationSyntaxs = classDeclarationSyntax.Members.OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();
    var barTypePropertyDeclarationSyntax = propertyDeclarationSyntaxs.FirstOrDefault( p => p.Identifier.Text == "BarType" );
    if ( barTypePropertyDeclarationSyntax != null )
    {
        var returnStatementSyntax = barTypePropertyDeclarationSyntax.DescendantNodes().OfType<ReturnStatementSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
        if ( returnStatementSyntax != null )
        {
            var typeOfExpressionSyntax = returnStatementSyntax.ChildNodes().OfType<TypeOfExpressionSyntax>().FirstOrDefault();
            if ( typeOfExpressionSyntax != null )
            {
                var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo( typeOfExpressionSyntax.Type );
                var symbolInfoSymbol = symbolInfo.Symbol;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use a `SyntaxWalker` for this:

```
public class TypeOfSyntaxWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
    private readonly SemanticModel _semanticModel;

    public ISymbol SymbolInfoSymbol { get; private set; }

    public TypeOfSyntaxWalker( SemanticModel semanticModel )
    {
        _semanticModel = semanticModel;
    }

    public override void VisitTypeOfExpression( TypeOfExpressionSyntax typeOfExpressionSyntax )
    {
        var parent = typeOfExpressionSyntax.Parent;
        if ( parent.Kind() == SyntaxKind.ReturnStatement )
        {
            var propertyDeclarationSyntax = parent.FirstAncestorOrSelf<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();
            if ( propertyDeclarationSyntax != null &&
                    propertyDeclarationSyntax.Identifier.ValueText == "BarType" )
            {
                var symbolInfo = _semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo( typeOfExpressionSyntax.Type );
                SymbolInfoSymbol = symbolInfo.Symbol;
            }
        }
        base.VisitTypeOfExpression( typeOfExpressionSyntax );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var classDeclarationSyntaxs = root.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
foreach ( var classDeclarationSyntax in classDeclarationSyntaxs )
{
    var typeOfSyntaxWalker = new TypeOfSyntaxWalker( semanticModel );
    typeOfSyntaxWalker.VisitClassDeclaration( classDeclarationSyntax );
    var symbolInfoSymbol = typeOfSyntaxWalker.SymbolInfoSymbol;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need the Semantic Model, which comes from a `Compilation` (with references & configuration).

You can then call <strike>`GetTypeSymbol()`</strike> `GetSymbolInfo()` on that node and cast to `INamedTypeSymbol`.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little please? I can't find a `GetTypeSymbol` on `member`

Comment: @MattBurland: That method is on the `SemanticModel`, which comes from a `Compilation` or a `Project`.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I'm still not seeing it. I edited the question a bit to include more of what I'm trying to do. I get a compilation from `project.GetCompilationAsync().Result` and I can get a `SemanticModel` from `compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree)`, but the resulting model still doesn't have a `GetTypeSymbol()` method

Comment: @MattBurland: Sorry; try `GetSymbolInfo()`